# Angular - property '$inject' does not exist on type error in VS2015

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm getting thousands of compiler errors in Visual Studio 2015 when I'm upgrading an AngularJS project to Angular 4. I've converted the app to a *hybrid* app that can successfully run AngularJS code alongside Angular4 code. Using CLI compilation, the typescript compilation is successful and the app works.

Most of the errors are in the *.d.ts files, however there are also a few errors in the *.ts files. I'm wondering if the errors in the *.ts are preventing correct compilation and if that's causing the other errors in the *.d.ts files.

One of the error types occurs in a *.ts file when I have something like this (which uses AngularJS code):

```
myCtrl.$inject = ['$window'];
```

I get this error:

```
Property '$inject' does not exist on type 'typeof myCtrl'
```

Assuming that I need to fix this specific error (and that this isn't just some other compilation issue that's causing $inject not to be recognised), what do I need to do? Here's the full code for one of my *.ts files that has the error:

```
(function() {

class myCtrl {

    window: any;

    constructor($window, $location) {
        this.window = $window;
    }

    myMethod(myParameter) {
        ... do stuff
    }
}

// *****error on this line*******
myCtrl.$inject = ['$window'];

class myDirective {

    restrict: string;
    controller: string;
    controllerAs: string;
    templateUrl: string;
    $document: any;
    $window: any;
    instance: any;

    constructor($document, $window) {
        this.restrict       = 'E';
        this.controller     = 'myCtrl';
        this.controllerAs   = 'myCtrlAlias';
        this.templateUrl    = '/yadda.html';
        this.$document      = $document;
        this.$window        = $window;
    }
    static myFactory($document, $window) {
        var instance = new myDirective($document, $window);
        return instance;
    }
}

angular
    .module('myModule', ['myDependency'])
    .directive('mainNav', ['$document', '$window', myDirective.myFactory])
    .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
})();
```

This is my tsconfig.json. I'm using tsc 1.8

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": true
  },
  "include": [ "**/*.ts" ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning class static and `prototype` properties directly causes type errors in TypeScript, because there are some limitations

TypeScript inherently supports class fields. It should be:

```
class myCtrl {
    static $inject = ['$window'];

    constructor($window, $location) { ... }
    ...
}
```

This also allows to have DI annotation right above constructor and avoid DI mistakes.